# Oracle error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: oracle

I tried the following anonymous block and get ORA-01847 error at line 14.

1. Is there anything wrong?
2. What is the definition of line 14th '**SSSS.FF**' into TO_CHAR FUNCTION?

Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'CONV_CIB';
TIME_START TIMESTAMP;
TIME_END TIMESTAMP;
EXECUTION_TIME TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable;
TIME_START := SYSTIMESTAMP;

select sysdate into procedure_name from dual;

TIME_END := SYSTIMESTAMP;

EXECUTION_TIME := TO_CHAR (TIME_END - TIME_START, 'SSSS.FF');

--dbms_output.put_line ('Start: ' || TIME_START);
--dbms_output.put_line ('  End: ' || TIME_END);
dbms_output.put_line (PROCEDURE_NAME ||'    PROCEDURE EXECUTION TIME: ' || TO_CHAR (TIME_END - TIME_START, 'SSSS.FF'));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EXECUTION_TIME);
EXECUTION_TIME := (EXECUTION_TIME || ' HRS');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EXECUTION_TIME);

END;
```

Comment: `TIME_END - TIME_START` will give you an INTERVAL data type. You can't format that, though you could extract just the seconds part. But you're assigning it to a TIMESTAMP variable, which doesn't make sense. And later you try to assign a string to that. What are you actually expecting to happen and be displayed?

Comment: I want the difference of anonymous block execution start and end time and display that in hour, minute and second that is in **HH:MI:SS** format.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is an error. You have declared variable `EXECUTION_TIME` as TIMESTAMP but you are assigning character value in it. As you changed the datatype of this variable to VARCHAR2, This will work like charm -

```
DECLARE
PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'CONV_CIB';
TIME_START TIMESTAMP;
TIME_END TIMESTAMP;
EXECUTION_TIME VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable;
TIME_START := SYSTIMESTAMP;

select sysdate into procedure_name from dual;

TIME_END := SYSTIMESTAMP;

EXECUTION_TIME := TO_CHAR (TIME_END - TIME_START, 'SSSS.FF');

--dbms_output.put_line ('Start: ' || TIME_START);
--dbms_output.put_line ('  End: ' || TIME_END);
dbms_output.put_line (PROCEDURE_NAME ||'    PROCEDURE EXECUTION TIME: ' || TO_CHAR (TIME_END - TIME_START, 'SSSS.FF'));

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EXECUTION_TIME);
EXECUTION_TIME := (EXECUTION_TIME || ' HRS');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (EXECUTION_TIME);

END;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/fZc7a367)

Comment: Thank you. 
Can you help me the meaning of **SSSS.FF** from line 14?

Comment: SSSS represents seconds and FF represents fraction of seconds.

Comment: @SadmanZIhan - SS represents seconds, so SSSS would show the seconds twice; if the time was 00:00:59.999 then SSSS.FF would give 5959.999. (There's also a separate SSSSS elements for seconds since midnight.) But you can't format intervals - `to_char(datetime)` accepts format and NLS arguments, and the docs implies they are used, but they are just ignored for intervals. You'll still get the full interval value, as you can see in the demo output.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything wrong?

Yes, as you state in the question, you get an ORA-01847 error at line 14.

Apart from that:

- You overwrite the procedure name with the current time.
- If you subtract two `TIMESTAMP`s you get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type as the result and not another `TIMESTAMP`.
- You cannot use `EXECUTION_TIME := (EXECUTION_TIME || ' HRS');` as the right-hand side results in a string and not a `TIMESTAMP`.

This will run without syntax errors:

```sql
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE_NAME VARCHAR2(100) := 'CONV_CIB';
  value          DATE;
  TIME_START     TIMESTAMP;
  TIME_END       TIMESTAMP;
  EXECUTION_TIME INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(9);
BEGIN
  dbms_output.enable;
  TIME_START := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  SELECT sysdate INTO value FROM DUAL;
  TIME_END := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  EXECUTION_TIME := TIME_END - TIME_START;
  dbms_output.put_line ('Start: ' || TIME_START);
  dbms_output.put_line ('  End: ' || TIME_END);
  dbms_output.put_line (
    PROCEDURE_NAME
    ||'    PROCEDURE EXECUTION TIME: ' || execution_time
  );
END;
/
```

and outputs:

> ```
> Start: 06-SEP-22 12.14.01.551337
>   End: 06-SEP-22 12.14.01.553333
> CONV_CIB    PROCEDURE EXECUTION TIME: +00 00:00:00.001996000
> ```

*DB<>Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GaHtukcd)*

Comment: Thank you.
Now I understand.
Can you help me about the output (+00 00:00:00.001996000) from the code?
Actually, I don't know what the meaning of **+00** of the output.

Comment: @SadmanZIhan - the `+` means it's a positive interval; the `00` is the number of days.